# if-statement inside function

Tags: c#, if-statement, lambda

I have this piece of code:

```
public static void Debug(string workName, string message, string logcontext, string exMessage = "")
{
    LogEventInfo logEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, logcontext, message + ": " + exMessage);
    ...
}
```

As you can see, the last parameter of the Debug method is optional (`string exMessage = ""`). That means that if I run this code as-is it will look fine if a exMessage arrived: `"...message: exMessage"`

However, If a exMessage wasn't provided, it will look like this: `"...message: "` (Note the trailing `:`).

Of course, this can easily be solved by using something like this:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(exMessage)
{
    ...(...,message + ": " + exMessage);
}
else
{
    ...(...,message);
}
```

I want a more beautiful approach. Like if there is something in the lines of:

```
...(...(!exMessage -> ,message | else -> ,message + ": " + exMessage));
```

Is there some way of doing this in-line if-statement in C#? Can I use lambdas some how? (I'm super-new to the whole concept of lambdas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LogEventInfo logEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, logcontext, message + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exMessage) ? ": " : string.Empty) + exMessage);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
 exMessage == "" ? message : message + ": " + exMessage
```

Answer (score 2):

There is its called the [?:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) operator. You use it like this:

```
var logText = string.IsNullOrEmpty(exMessage) ? message : message + ": " + exMessage;
```

Comment: Thanks :D Allthough I accepted nsgocev's answer because he was first ^^